# jQuery - How to mask credit card number during input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

My goal is to have a form similar to http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/. Ive tried viewing the source code of that page, but it is beyond my expertise, so I tried to rewrite the code using jquery. I also want to mask the input after the first 2 digits are typed.

The problem:

Clearing the displayed CC image,  appears to only work on FireFox, and is unpredictable.
Once the input is masked to conform to the credit card type, the cursor is thrown to the end of the input box

What am I doing wrong here? There has to be a much simpler way to do this

**Fidle with code**:http://jsfiddle.net/nh7qqfgx/

(for the sake of convince, colored rectangular divs are placeholders for the actual card logos)

**Code:**

```
$('#ccnumber').validateCreditCard(function (result) {
        // this will execute everytime the value of the `#cc_number` field changes



        if (result.card_type == null) {
            $("#ccHolder").removeClass();

        }
        if (result.card_type != null) {
            cardtype = result.card_type.name;


            $("#ccHolder").addClass(result.card_type.name);

            if (result.card_type.name === 'visa') { //if the card is Visa
                $("#ccnumber").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });

            }
            if (result.card_type.name === 'amex') { //if the card is American Express
                $("#ccnumber").mask("999-999999-999999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });

            }
            if (result.card_type.name === 'mastercard') { //if the card is MasterCard
                $("#ccnumber").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });

            }
            if (result.card_type.name === 'discover') { //if the card is Discover
                $("#ccnumber").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });

            }
            if (result.card_type.name === 'JCB') { //if the card is JCB
                $("#ccnumber").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });

            }
            if (result.card_type.name === 'Diners Club') { //if the card is Diners Club
                $("#ccnumber").mask("999-999999-99999", { placeholder: " ", autoclear: false });
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use masks. They're terrible.

Comment: "Masked" has a specific meaning in form inputs (showing bullets rather than the characters entered). I think you mean "formatted"?